# Sequelize.or returns Limit 1 rather than or result

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, sequelize.js

i'm using SequelizeJS(MySql) with Passportjs for authentication 
when i write

```
User.find(db.Sequelize.or({ 'username': username }, { 'email': req.body.email }) )
            .then((user) => {console.log(user)}
```

or

```
User.find({$or:[({ 'username': username }, { 'email': req.body.email })]} )
```

Generats

> Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `Picture`, `role`, `Description`, `joinedAt`, `Social`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User` LIMIT 1;

I don't understand what happen , i'm using or and it generates query with limit 1 !

my user Model

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-node');
const db = require('../Config/db');

module.exports = function () {
    let DataType = db.Sequelize;
    let User = db.sequelize.define('User', {
        name: { type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false },
        username: { type: DataType.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false },
        email: { type: DataType.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false, validate: { isEmail: true } },
        password: {
            type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false, set: function (pass) {
                let newPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(pass);
                this.setDataValue('password', newPassword);
            }
        },
        Picture: { type: DataType.STRING, default: '#' },
        role: { type: DataType.STRING, default: 'user',allowNull: false },
        Description: { type: DataType.TEXT },
        joinedAt: { type: DataType.DATE, defaultValue: DataType.NOW },
        Social: { type: DataType.TEXT }
    }, {
            classMethods: {
                associate: function (models) {
                    User.hasMany(models.Post);
                }
            }
        }, {
            instanceMethods: {
                comparePassword: function (password) {
                    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
                }
            }
        });

    return User;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function `Model.find()` in Sequelize, so it looks like you are probably calling [`Model.findOne()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findoneoptions-promiseinstance) which applies the `LIMIT 1` to your query. To find all of the results, you need to use [`Model.findAll()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance).

You should use the [query operator](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#operators) $or, but it needs to be inside a `where` element with an array of OR values. See an example below.

```js
User.findAll({
  where: {
    $or: [
      username: username,
      email: req.body.email,
    ],
  }
})
.then(users => console.log(users));
```

Comment: `find` is an alias for `findOne` , but it works now with where 
Thank you, the problem docs doesn't offer any kind of examples like this.

Comment: It must be generated dynamically, you are correct that it's not in the docs and I didn't see it with static analysis either. I would recommend sticking to the methods in the official docs.